# Deleting a substring from a string

Tags: c, string

When I run this program , I introduce for example as string `Ana are mere` and as substring `are`. And the resulted string is `Ana  mereere`, not `Ana mere`. Could you tell me why?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *str_rem(char *sir, char *subsir) 
{
    int i, j,k;
    int loc = -1; //subsirul nu a fost gasit(presupunem)
    for (i = 0; sir[i] && (loc==-1);i++)
    for (j = i, k = 0; sir[j] == subsir[k];j++,k++)
    if (subsir[k + 1] == 0) loc = i;
    if (loc != -1) //subsirul a fost gasit
    {
        for (k = 0; subsir[k]; k++)
            ; //bucla nu face nimic!! dorim sa obtinem cate elemente are subsirul
        printf("\nSubsirul este format din %d elemente\n", k);
        for (j = loc, i = loc + k; sir[i]; j++, i++)
            sir[j] = sir[i];
        sir[i] = '\0';

    }
    return (sir);
}
void main()
{
    char *sir;
    sir = (char*)malloc(255*sizeof(char));
    printf("Introduceti sirul: ");
    gets(sir);
    char *subsir;
    subsir = (char*)malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Introduceti subsirul care doriti sa fie cautat: ");
    gets(subsir);
    printf("Sirul %s rezultat dupa stergerea subsirului %s este: %s\n", sir, subsir, str_rem(sir, subsir));
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`, first of all.

Comment: You need to bung in a null character to terminate the string

Comment: You have `sir[i] = '\0'` when you want to put the NULL at `sir[j] = '\0'` since that's the new ending

Comment: @Constantin It is simply an awful code! You should enclose each body of for statement in parentheses. Otherwise it is very difficult to understand what the function does.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow bracket-less constructs are fine. In fact, that's the only thing that is fine in this code.

Comment: @Quentin We have different ideas about the good style programming. I am sure that who writes code in such a style simply should not be a programmer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The necessity of brackets is open to debate, but this code has a multitude of other, much worse problems: pointless heap allocation of small buffers, `gets`, casting `malloc`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow wow, you do feel strongly about it ! I was just surprised that the only thing you quoted about that "awful code" (which it is) is a harmless stylistic choice :p

Comment: @szczurcio  I am sure that there can not be a debate if you deal with a qualified progarrmer.  A debate can be only with a beginner who understand nothing in programming.

Comment: @Quentin It is a law that any bad written code contains a bug. So there is no sense to discuss the code until it will be rewritten. It is obvious that it contains bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Line

```
sir[i] = '\0'
```

should be

```
sir[j] = '\0'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code:

Your code is not indented properly.  I would even say it is indented deceptively! Take the time and care to indent your code with 4 spaces per level, and use braces for any non trivial block, that will prevent many bugs from creeping into it.

```
char *str_rem(char *sir, char *subsir) 
{
    int i, j, k;
```

Use English for your comments, it will help readers from the rest of the world. Not everyone understands romanian.

```
    int loc = -1; //subsirul nu a fost gasit(presupunem)

    for (i = 0; sir[i] && (loc == -1); i++) {
```

Why not use `strstr()` to find the match?

```
        for (j = i, k = 0; sir[j] == subsir[k]; j++, k++) {
            if (subsir[k + 1] == 0) loc = i;
```

Why 2 separate tests? The conditions are equivalent.

```
            if (loc != -1) { //subsirul a fost gasit
```

Why rescan for `'\0'`? `k += 1` would suffice.

```
                for (k = 0; subsir[k]; k++) {
                    //bucla nu face nimic!! dorim sa obtinem cate elemente are subsirul
                    continue;  // use this to emphasize the empty body.
                }

                printf("\nSubsirul este format din %d elemente\n", k);
                for (j = loc, i = loc + k; sir[i]; j++, i++) {
                    sir[j] = sir[i];
                }
```

Here is a bug: You should set `sir[j]` instead of `sir[i]`.

```
                sir[i] = '\0';
```

Another bug here: given how your code is written, you should break out of the loop here.  If you fix the other bug above, the loop will keep comparing beyond the end of both strings.

```
            }
        }
    }
```

Remove the `()`, `return` is a statement, not a function call.

```
    return (sir);
}
```

The proper prototype should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

```
void main()
{
```

Why use `malloc` instead of defining a local array `char sir[255];`?

```
    char *sir;
    sir = (char*)malloc(255*sizeof(char));

    printf("Introduceti sirul: ");
```

Never EVER use `gets`, use `fgets(sir, 255, stdin);` instead, and test the return value. And strip the `'\n'` with `sir[strcspn(sir, "\n")] = '\0';`

```
    gets(sir);
```

Same as above: use `char subsir[255];`

```
    char *subsir;
    subsir = (char*)malloc(255 * sizeof(char));

    printf("Introduceti subsirul care doriti sa fie cautat: ");
```

Use `fgets(subsir, 255, stdin)` and `subsir[strcspn(subsir, "\n")] = '\0';`:

```
    gets(subsir);
```

Wrap long lines for readability:

There is another bug here: you modify `sir` before it is printed by `printf`.  You should split this line into 2 separate calls to `printf`, one with the input strings, one with the resulting string.

```
    printf("Sirul %s rezultat dupa stergerea subsirului %s este: %s\n", 
           sir, subsir, str_rem(sir, subsir));
```

Finally, this call is non standard, use `getchar()` instead.

```
    _getch();
}
```

Furthermore, you should test if `subsir` is an empty string, your code invokes undefined behaviour for this special case.  Also what about multiple matches? Are you supposed to remove them all or just the first occurrence as you try to do now?